# Php RESTful WebService parameter best way?

Tags: php, web-services, rest, post, put

What is the best way to consume webservice with parameter in php using RESTful?

If I want to POST or PUT with some variables as parameter from the client which way the parameter should be on? Http header, body, or from the url?

And what is the pros and cons?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Secret info like apicode etc should be in Header, and values should be send through POST method, It's totally depends on the requirement to pass variables through GET or POST...